# Why doesn't this simple bash regex return true?

Tags: regex, bash

If I do `[[ "0" =~ "^[0-9]+$" ]] && echo hello` at a terminal I would expect to see the word "hello"

However, nothing gets printed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `[[ "0" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]`

Comment: [Recommended reading](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns#Regular_Expressions-1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the double quotes present in your regex. ie, don't enclose your regex pattern within double quotes.

```
[[ "0" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
[[ "0" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && echo hello
```

Note that the second part is not surrounded with double quotes, otherwise it'll be treated as the *string* "^[0-9]+$" and not a regex. To confirm that, try:

```
[[ "^[0-9]+$" =~ "^[0-9]+$" ]] && echo hello
```

Comment: Slight technicality: the right hand side is still treated as a regular expression (`[[ foo =~ "fo" ]]` would still succeed, for example). The difference is that any *metacharacters* inside the regex will be treated literally.